# google calendar sync specifications

Tags: csv, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am working on a web application that among other things maintains its own calendar. I want to allow people with gmail accounts to subscribe to this calendar feed. Based on the research I made I can do it by outputting an iCalendar formatted file into a publicly accessible location and direct google calendar to subscribe to this location. What I am trying to find is some technical documentation about how google performs these requests for feed updates, so I can generate the csv files correctly and efficiently. For example what is the frequency of the requests, what is the format of those requests and so on. All I could find API documentation about how to pull information from google calendar. But this is not what I need. Basically I want to create the csv files on demand instead of maintaining them constantly, hence I need to be able to intercept google requests for calendar sync and handle them accordingly. Can somebody point me into the right direction?

Comment: Do you want to know about google calendar synchronization? https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync. In google calendar API documentation, there is technical information on how events are inserted,updated,deleted by sending API request with Oauth Authorization. Let me know if your question is different?

Comment: @SGC Calendar API allows for my application to push or receive updates to/from google calendar. What I need is the other way around. I need google calendar to sync to my application's calendar. I know it is possible by subscribing to calendar feed, but I am looking for more technical information regarding how this sync process works.